# Special case when finding min key for dictionary in Python

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following:

```
x = {"A":2, "1":2,"0":1, "5":2}

print(min(x))

0
```

This returns zero as it should. Ideally I would like it to return any letter that is a key before looking at the minimum number. That is if there is a letter A-z that is present as a key return that otherwise return the minimum number. Anyone have any basic and/or simple solution for this?

Comment: use the min function with a custom key that looks for the position in `string.ascii_leters + string.digits`. something like `min(x.keys(), key=lambda x: (string.ascii_letters + string.digits).index(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers come before letters by ASCII code:

```
>>> ord('9')
57
>>> ord('A')
65
```

So we can just check if the `max()` is a digit. If it is, then there aren't any letter keys, and we'll go with the `min()`.

```
x = {"A":2, "1":2,"0":1, "5":2}
m = max(x)
if m.isdigit():
    print(min(x))
else:
    print(m)
```

You can also use the `isdigit()` result as an index to the sorted list of keys:

```
x = {"A":2, "1":2,"0":1, "5":2}
s = sorted(x)
print(s[s[-1].isdigit()-1])
```

Comment: This is clever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply:

```
min( [ key for key in x.keys() if key in string.letters ] )
```

Comment: This doesn't account for digits.

Comment: @veggie1 I want to leave this answer as is, so that OP can modify it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_min(x):
    letters  = [l for l in x.keys() if not str(l).isdigit()]
    digits = [d for d in x.keys() if str(d).isdigit()]
    if letters:
        min_letter = min(letters)
    if digits:
        min_digit = min(digits)
    return min_letter or min_digit


x = {"A":2, "1":2,"0":1, "5":2}
find_min(x)  # 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function to convert digit keys to more than any letters, and use it as the `key`:

```
def func(a):
    if a.isdigit():
        return chr(int(a) + ord('z') + 1)
    else:
        return a

x = {"A":2, "1":2,"0":1, "5":2}
print(min(x, key=func))
```